# Hide and show upon onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

My function is working perfectly. But i cant seems to hide the button or show new buttons upon using onclick function.

Sample:

```
  var download = document.getElementById('download');
  function RemoveDoc(Doc)
  {
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","functions/remove.php?Doc="+Doc,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

        download.syle.visibility='hidden';
        download.style.display ='none'
        document.getElementById("RemoveMsg").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.send();

    return false;
```

}

My form

```
   //I tried to add in the download button to be hidden here but still invalid
   <input type="submit" id="remove" name="Name" value="Remove" onclick="return RemoveDoc(this.value); document.getElementById('download').style.visibility='hidden'; return false;" />
   <input type="submit" id="download" value="download"/> //want to hide this button.
   <input type="file" id="reupload"/> //want to show this.
```

I tried display = 'none' also invalid for my download to be disappear after function called out successfully. Kindly advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove return from your call, make it

```
onclick="RemoveDoc(this.value); document.getElementById('download').style.visibility='hidden'; return false;"
```

Using return was making the statements after your function call unreachable.

Answer (score 4):

```
download.style.visibility='hidden';
```

Comment: This is correct. JS will throw error in syle typo - download.syle.visibility='hidden';

Answer (score 0):

You can only return one value. You have two return statements but it will never get to the second return statement.

Instead have just one return statement

```
<input type="submit" id="remove" name="Name" value="Remove" onclick="RemoveDoc(this.value); document.getElementById('download').style.visibility='hidden'; return false;" />
```